# How to retrive/display column names and its data based on dynamic query in spring data jpa?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

How to retrieve/display column names and its data based on dynamic query in spring data jpa?

Example dynamic query be like
Select empid, empname, address from emp (or)
Select productiD, pname, price, pquantity from Product

I don't want to map entity just need to display data?

Comment: You can use `JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;`.For more look over here https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/

Answer (score 0):

For a completely dynamic query Spring Data JPA doesn't offer any special support, so in order to integrate it into your repository you'll need to [define a custom method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior).

Since you only want a `Map` anyway the easiest way might be to use a SQL query, execute it with a `JdbcTemplate` and have a simple `ResultSetExtractor` that inserts the values from the `ResultSet` into a `Map`.

If you want to utilise the mapping information of JPA you might construct a query using the Criteria API where you explicitly specify all the columns you want and specify `Tuple` as target type.